# Safe way to uninstall old version of python

Tags: python, macos, installation

I want to update my Python framework on Mac and delete the old versions
but I am not sure if is safe to

```
rm -fr /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.4 - 2.5 - 2.6 -3.0 etc.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, it's safe.
The Mac's system python's are in `/System/Library/...`.
.dmg's downloaded and installed from python.org are placed in `/Library/...`.
Don't delete the /System ones, but the /Library ones are user installed, so they should be safe to delete.

Comment: I personally have done this-- I've installed python.org's .dmg's, then removed them and installed from source with `homebrew`.

Comment: To completely delete the old ones, you can also delete the corresponding folders installed by the python.org installers into `/Applications`, either `/Applications/MacPython 2.n` or `/Applications/Python m.n`.  The final piece is to delete the corresponding symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` (*not* `/usr/bin`!)

Comment: +1 Ned. Agreed. I forgot those steps, but I remember doing them.

Comment: It's safer not to mess with /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/

Comment: I'm not able to do the above command. I get "Operation not permitted" even when I use sudo. @snapshoe

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not safe. Generally, don't mess with the Python that comes with your OS, many system tools depends on having a specific version of Python.

Comment: Yes, you should not mess with Python files that are part of an OS distribution.  But the paths referenced by the OP are *not* to the Pythons that come with OS X, rather they are ones installed by the python.org installer or other third-party installers.

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework is not the system one