# Why 'build applet' app in python 2.7 application folder is unable to delete in osx 10.7.3?

Tags: python, osx-lion, uninstallation

I installed python 2.7 on in my mac air osx 10.7,but i found out that python 3.2 is recent version, so I decided to delete python 2.7 and replace it with version 3.2. As I delete python 2.7, I encountered few problems.

1.application called "build applet" is unable to delete. I moved whole python 2.7 application folder to trash and empty the trash. Other apps like IDLE and python launcher was removed but build applet app still remains in trash. And now if I try to empty the trash, it says that build applet app is currently used so I can't delete that.

2.I installed python 3.2 after I deleted 2.7 python, but this time, there are apps called "python launcher" and "python" that have exactly same icon(rocket launcher). I tried to open python app but nothing happened.

How I remove python 2.7 from computer and use 3.2? And what is "build applet" app and why it is unable to delete?

Comment: You didn't need to uninstall 2.7 to install 3.2. `Build applet` is unique to the Apple distributed version of Python, and doesn't come in the Python.org distribution. I'm not sure why it doesn't let you delete it, but you don't have to anyway... (Have you tried `rm` from the terminal, by the way?)

Comment: In fact, it's a good idea to keep 2.7 around because a lot of python scripts are written for 2.x and won't run in 3.2. (They'll generate syntax errors).

Comment: I'm not familiar with terminal program and computer language. What is 'rm' means and how do I use it? And also, I already deleted IDLE and other apps in 2.7 python folder. Is that mean I deleted python 2.7 language from computer?

Comment: And now, build applet app is not opening and says that it is damaged. How do I have to fix this problem?

Comment: Type `terminal` into Finder. Open the Terminal application. Type `python` in the command line. See what happens. If python _does_ run, the first few lines before the `>>>` prompt will tell you what version it's running.

Comment: Note that, since Mac OSX comes with it's own Python distribution, you most likely had TWO python 2.7 installations on your computer (since you said you installed 2.7 yourself). If python runs in terminal, then you haven't deleted the built in distribution. I would then take `build applet` and place it back where you found it.

Comment: I would see if you can obtain a copy of the directory `/System/Library/Framework/Python.Framework` from someone else with OS X 10.7. Copy over whatever you have left in that directory. That might repair it.

Comment: Thank you for lot of helps. I typed python in terminal and it said python 2.7 is running. And I put build applet back to application folder but it is still not working. Does that mean I need to download it again or I have to delete 3.2? Thanks.

Comment: You know, I can't help you with `build applet` issue, but you really don't need it. [Here's](http://docs.python.org/using/mac.html#distributing-python-applications-on-the-mac) a short section in the python doc's about Build Applet. If you ask me, you can just use another, more robust, distribution system.  As far as running 3.2 goes, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261429/install-python-3-1-on-mac-os-x-version-10-5-8)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation: after deleting the "/Developer-old" directory, I was unable to empty the trash due to 2 occurrences of "Build Applet.app" not being deleted.

To solve this, I had to delete the files using the command line (I was sure I could delete these, since "/Developer-old" wasn't in use anymore - your case may be different):

```
rm -rf /path/to/Build\ Applet.app
```