# Clean Mac from different python versions

Tags: python, macos

I've started to use python and recently i've bought my first mac.
I saw that Mountain Lion comes with their own python versions, despite i've decided to install a new python 2.7.5, and also Django and MySQL-Python. Everything works fine.
I've decided to try scipy and following the installed steps suggested by the official site with macports It seemed that macports installed another version 2.7.5 of python. Now if i try to run python in my terminal and import numpy it fails.
I saw that when i run python in my terminal, it execute

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

But if I go in

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
```

and run ./python i can import django and numpy modules but not MySQLdb modules.

I'm really confused how I can fix that mess.

I would like to have just one Python version installed in one place with all the modules I need. 
Or please suggest something to clean that mess, know and have the control to what modules I have, where they are and how to import them! And also control which version of Python I want to run.

Edit 10/27/2013: i've solved following the link suggested in the comment, deleting all versions in /Library/ and all simlinks in /usr/local/bin, after that i changed to the path i wanted the py interpreter in my bash_profile. 
Actually the problems seems to be created by macports that has installed numpy using the py interpreter installed under /System/, so i changed my default py interpreter to that installed under /System/ and installed the rest of packages i need. Now everything works as i want.

Comment: you should try http://superuser.com/

Comment: See this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950819/safe-way-to-uninstall-old-version-of-python

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't mess around with the built-in version of Python. I had some real issues with my Mac when I did that a few months ago.

You could try Canopy instead. It's a Python development environment which is great for writing and executing code. Any packages you need can be easily added (or removed) using the package manager. https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/