# What is the best way to set up Jupyter notebook with virtual env on OSx

Tags: macos, python-3.x, installation, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am about starting to learn data science using jupyter notebook with python. I have set python 3.6 as well as default one 2.7 came with Mac.

I don't mind to get rid of python 3.6 (if it is easy...) I woould like to know what is the best way to them up.

So my question is

Q1:
Is this a best way? Get rid of python 3.6, go to anaconda to download python 3.6 together with jupyter all at once.

Q2:
If so how to uninstall python 3.6 correctly?

I am sort of scared to deal with all these dependancies, default path, manipulating file directories and etc if you know what I mean.

Thanks x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the use of anaconda because from my point of view is a cleaner approach.

You do not need to get rid of your Python 3.6 installation anaconda will be installed in a different path.

From my point of view anaconda is easy to use and clean:

You can create a venv easily:

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

Activate your venv:

```
activate yourenvname
```

And is really useful for installing packages with external dependencies, one of the best perks of anaconda in my opinion:

```
conda install -c anaconda scipy
```

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scipy

If you like to uninstall Python 3.6 check this [Safe way to uninstall old version of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950819/safe-way-to-uninstall-old-version-of-python)

Comment: Thank you so much. I also found [Create virtual environments for python with conda](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/)  I just installed anaconda, but I get `-bash: conda: command not found`. Tried > export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH But no luck. If you know how to set new VARIABLE on bash_profile, please let me know...

Comment: There are numerous questions about adding anaconda to the PATH, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029333/how-to-check-that-the-anaconda-package-was-properly-installed

Also check if the path ~/anaconda3/bin exists in your machine.

Comment: There are many different answers for PATH, mine worked with `export PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` Thanks!, you were right anaconda3 was not existing. I have set up, activated env now installing scipy. Very appreciate it!!!